# How do I label tabs in tabbed activity in android?

Tags: android

I have been getting an error for API 19 that this tab return null pointer exception while labelling tabbed view? Is there a simple way to label tabs like this in tabbed activity?[labbeled tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4PPh.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. We cannot help you debug code that we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

See this [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) from android official website.